# Chrome DNS cache not expiring if same domain is requested

Tags: google-chrome, dns

When building a dynamic video stream service for my own needs, I noticed a problem which I need to solve. I am setting a `TTL=1` on the A record and change it dynamically but didn't see a change in resolved IP. As mentioned in other questions, Chrome is always using 60s TTL internally, but even minutes later the old IP was being resolved (system is resolving the new IP). Same goes when I use the hosts file for quick tests.

What I noticed is that Chrome is not honoring the internal TTL when there are new requests present to same host. So the browser needs to stop any requests to this domain for more than a minute in order to have the DNS flushed and browser doing new `HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_JOB`. What I need to know is if there is clear documentation on how I can avoid this? Any suggestions are welcome.

*Note: using the `chrome://net-internals` is not a solution, I need to have this fully automated.*

Comment: The web browser caches web-pages as well. Are you sure you're not confusing the Browser cache of the web content with the Browser caching a DNS record?  Can you test a different browser like Firefox or Edge?

Comment: @madacoda I am completely sure what I am talking about and it's the browser dns cache.